# How to refresh inputboxes in JSF after ajax submit command?

Tags: jsf

I have an inputText and an inputTextArea in JSF (shown below) that I carry out an ajax action on. However, after my ajax event, the values remain in the input boxes. Is there a simple way to refresh these text boxes after the commandButton is involked? Thanks.

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <td><div class="white"><H2>Comments</H2></div>

        <h:inputText class="inputboxes" id="username"
                    value="#{commentBean.comment.commentname}" size="20">
                    </h:inputText><br/><br/>
        <h:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="55" id="comment"  class="inputbox" value="#{commentBean.comment.commentText}"
                    size="20" /></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td></td>


            <td><h:commandButton id="update"
                    action="#{commentBean.addComment(searchBean.companyId)}" class="myButton2" value="Add Comment" >
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":results"/>

                </h:commandButton></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
<h:form id="results">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <h:dataTable value="#{commentBean.viewComments(searchBean.companyId)}" var="c">

                <h:column>
                <div class="commentsbox">#{c.commentText}</div>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                <div class="boldfont">#{c.commentdate}</div>
                </h:column>

        <td><h:column>
                <div class="commentname">#{c.commentname}</div>
                </h:column>
        </td>

                </h:dataTable>

            </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view :

```
 <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":results, username, comment"/>
```

In your backing bean, in the `addComment()` method :

```
comment.setCommentname(null);
comment.setCommentText(null);
```

or simply (I guess only)

```
comment = null;
```